# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4

Tags: android

How to fix this issue.

1)

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4.

2)

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
    } 

    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' 
    } 
} 

allprojects { 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
        maven { 
            url "jitpack.io" 
        } 
    } 
} 

task clean(type: Delete) { 
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

Comment: Would you please share build.gradle file?

Comment: buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
this is my project level build.gradle

Comment: Please share your app label build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `jitpack.io` maven repo in `allprojects` node inside project level `build.gradle`

```
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
```

See https://github.com/scottyab/showhidepasswordedittext and https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: yes already I have ..but Today I am Update the android studio 3.3.1

Comment: buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
} this my project level build.gradle

Comment: Not sure but did you try using https://jitpack.io  with "https://"? or probably gradle is not syncing properly after upgrade. try to restart after invalidating cache.